# can different types of objects be put in one array?

Tags: c++

Here is the thing, I have several `std::map`s, like this:

```
std::map<int, std::set> map_1;
std::map<int, std::string> map_2;
std::map<int, long> map_3;
...
```

And there are also several numbers, each of which relates to one map listed above, like

```
1 -> map_2
2 -> map_1
3 -> map_3
...
```

What I'm trying to do is that, put all the maps into one array, then access each number's map
will be like accessing the element of that array, like this:

```
arr = [map_2, map_1, map_3];
// let x be a number
map_x = arr[x];
do_something(map_x)
```

This way, I can relieve myself of writing `switch...case`, right?

But can I put them together and how?

Comment: What for do you need it? Seems to me better to change your design.

Comment: @DenisErmolin, well, I'm just trying to avoid writing `switch...case...`

Comment: write an op[] and hide the switch in it

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb, well, ...

Comment: Not sure you can, because of the different types of ``map_1``, ``map_2`` and ``map_3``. Even in a language like Java, that let you just create an array of objects, you'd need to switch on the actual type of the object you dereference to find out what to do with it.

Comment: Post some code of how that switch case would look so we can see what you're doing.

Comment: You can use a union type in the array declaration, but you'll need a discriminator to specify the actual type of each element, and then you'll need a switch.

Comment: How were you planning on declaring `map_x` and `do_something()` so that the assignment would work for all of the array elements?

Comment: You are trying to reinvent polymorphism...

Comment: Do you have one map for every number or do you share these 3 maps among all numbers?

Answer (score 1):

The right way to do things like this is with classes. Create a base class `map`, and templated subclasses for the specific types of maps. Then you can create an array of `map*` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution is to use [boost::variant](http://www.boost.org/libs/variant).

Put all your map types into variant (`boost::variant<std::map<int, std::set>, std::map<int, std::string>, std::map<int, long>>`), then write visitor like (`do_something` should be already overloaded, right?):

```
class do_something_visitor
    : public boost::static_visitor<>
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    void operator()(T &map) const
    {
        do_something(map);
    }
};
```

Then apply visitation (`boost::apply_visitor`) over items in your array of variants.